# jQuery ajax error when data fetching

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.2.0 and jQuery. I can't get fetch data via jQuery and PhP

```
function postolayi(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'giriskontrol.php',
    data:$('#girisForm').serialize(),
    success:function(cevap){
      $("#uyari").html(cevap) 
    }
  })
}
```

index.php

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" id="girisForm">
  <input  id="isim" name="isim" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="isim" required autofocus>
  <input name="sifre" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="şifre" id="sifre" required>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="postolayi();">
  Giriş Yap</button>
</form>
<div class="alert alert-warning" id="uyari"></div>
```

giriskontrol.php

```
<?php
$POST["isim"] = $isim;
echo $isim;
?>
```

I can't fetch data. Please somebody help.

I changed as

```
<?php
$isim = $POST["isim"];
echo $isim;
?>
```

But still not working.

Comment: Peki dedikleri gibi yaptim ama caismadi. Bana yardimci olur musun tekrar bir gozatip

Comment: Sorun php tatafindaysa yardimci olurum. Hata olarak ne aliyorsun soruya yapistirsana.

Comment: butona tıkladığındda hiçbir şey olmuyor formdan girileni yazdirmak istiyorum. soruna yazamiyorum cunku 8 saat beklemem gerek. yani yazdiramiyorum sayfaya

Comment: Php tarafinda bir sorun yok gibi, jquery uzmanlik alanim degil. Yardimci olacagim tek sey sorunu upvote etmek olur onu da yapiyorum. Kolay gelsin.

Comment: Soruna cevap yazan puani en yuksek adamin cevabina yorum yaz. Hala calismiyor diye. Belki yardimci olur.

Comment: Hocam sorunu çözdüm çok komik :)
$POST["isim"]; yerine
$_POST["isim"]; olacak :)

Comment: Nice to see you find a solution for your issue. Goodnight.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the post variable here:

```
$_POST["isim"] = $isim;
```

What you probably wanted was:

```
$isim = $_POST["isim"];
echo $isim;
```

Comment: That Super Global Must be `$_POST`

Comment: Thanks, hadn't noticed.

Comment: 3 answers and all of them copy paste (:

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too :D

Answer (score 0):

In your php file
Switch:

```
$POST["isim"] = $isim;
```

with

```
$isim = $POST["isim"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your assignment on your php page to

```
<?php
$isim = $_POST["isim"];
echo $isim;
?>
```